# How can I change the view of jqGrid

Tags: jquery

i use the standard jqGrid , i want to personnalise itto be like the same as the template that it existe.
SO how can I change the color, the FONT and so on .

Comment: try to change the css of jQgrid, jquery ui css, as jQgrid uses both css files. or create another css file and refer it below all other css files and you can override the existing css styles init.

Comment: download Redmond. Extract the downloaded file jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom and paste it under themes -> redmond folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override css files provided, try to use F12 and check the css file name which is getting applied. and you can override this css file and classes with your own